# Relocating and renaming classes using namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-0

I have a number of older classes that I'd like to transition into a [PSR-0](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal) style directory. I'd like a sanity check on my process.

1. Rename and relocate the existing `FooPerson.class.php` file to `Foo/Person.php`.
2. Create `namespace Foo` in `Person.php`, and update all class references to be namespace-compatible as appropriate.
3. For compatibility with old code, create a new `FooPerson.class.php` with this content:

   ```
   <?php

   require 'autoload.php'; // our psr-0 autoloader
   class_alias( '\Foo\Person', 'FooPerson' );
   ```

My hope is that this will enable transparent instantiation using either `new FooPerson` or `new \Foo\Person`. Initial testing seems to support this. Are there pitfalls I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any pitfalls. However, I suggest to use another approach, because this one may let you miss the one or another old classname. Either you remove `FooPerson` completely, in which case you will realize the hard way, where you forgot to change the classname, or create a dummy class, that helps you keep track with a message when someone tries to use it.

```
// File 'FooPerson.php'

trigger_error("Class 'FooPerson'", E_USER_DEPRECATED);
class FooPerson extends \Foo\Person {}
```

Because the class-to-filename-mapping is valid according the psr-0 standard, this file gets loaded by your autoloader too. In the case it *is* loaded by the autoloader, a `E_USER_DEPRECATED` is emitted and you can fix it.

Comment: Yeah, good call re: triggering an error. `E_USER_DEPRECATED` is most appropriate.

Comment: @Adam, @netcoder: Of course. Don't know why, but in my world there were no `E_USER_DEPRECATED` and it will come in 5.4 ^^